# Unable to get work info at Facebook Login android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, android-facebook

I have integrated facebook login in my app.
I want to get the education and work history of user. I have got the permission from facebook, but I am not getting the data in response.

Below are the screenshots of permissions:

[image: App Taking Permissions]

[image: Facebook Review Page]

Below is my code for login:

```
facebookLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","user_work_history"));

facebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    // Get facebook data from login
                    Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);


                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();




private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {

    try {
        bundle = new Bundle();
        String id = object.getString("id");

        try {
            URL profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=200&height=150");
            Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic + "");
            bundle.putString("profile_pic", profile_pic.toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        bundle.putString("idFacebook", id);
        if (object.has("first_name"))
            bundle.putString("first_name", object.getString("first_name"));
        if (object.has("last_name"))
            bundle.putString("last_name", object.getString("last_name"));
        if (object.has("email"))
            bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
        if (object.has("gender"))
            bundle.putString("gender", object.getString("gender"));
        if (object.has("birthday"))
            bundle.putString("birthday", object.getString("birthday"));
        if (object.has("location"))
            bundle.putString("location", object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));
        System.out.println("BUNDLEEE: "+bundle);
        return bundle;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bundle;
}
```

And My Response that I am getting from facebook

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"635531373278990","first_name":"Prakhar","last_name":"Srivastava","email":"srivastava.prakhar91@gmail.com","gender":"male"}, error: null}
```

I am not getting work and education related data, I am unable to find out what is wrong.

Comment: user have work history?=)

Comment: @PeDuCKA Yes, I am logging in with my account, I have work history.. that too public..

Comment: try adding user_work_history to your bundle parameters